# Excel Not Saving External Source Links, Having to Relink Every Time it Opens

Tags: excel, external-links

I have two Excel files (Microsoft 365)that were communicating fine one day and then the next day, it prompts me to update links. Other files have also stopped updating links. I also tried on a different computer (still 365) and get the same message.

I update the links and open the source file and it works fine. I close it and go back in and it prompts me to relink the links again.

I've selected "Don't display the alert and update links" under the Startup Prompt

[image]
Under Trust Center I Selected "Enable all Data Connections and "Enable automatic update for all Workbook Links" and "Enable all Linked Data Types".
[image]
I also went into Advanced under Options and selected "Update links to other documents" and deselected "Ask to update automatic links".

[image]

I do not know what else to do. It was working fine one day and not the next. As far as I know, there were no updates.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.